# Help Center 'What topics can I ask about here?' is missing an explanation for primary close reasons

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

At this question, I just felt unable to answer the [OPs comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871452/64-bit-linux-g-passing-struct-btw-two-threads-via-pipe/32872286#comment53575795_32871452) concisely.

The help center article I have linked in my responding comment ([What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) misses to explain, why asking about opinions (which is a primary close reason) is off-topic.

Also, if we're already on it, *too broad* isn't explained there as well.

I think just adding the explanations from the close vote pop-up would already suffice to improve the help centre article.

As @Becuzz mentioned in [their answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307138/1413395) and comments, the information is already available in other help center articles. Though I believe, that information should be just as prominent as it is mentioned in the close reasons which pop up in 1st place, when a question is voted to be closed as *off-topic*.

---

I think improving the help center regarding this, could also help to reduce some frequent Meta SO noisy questions, that want to have explanations, why questions were closed for these reasons<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I well know people don't read, but anyway there could be a little positive effect.</sub>

Comment: Good one. So obvious but never implemented.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to get at the full list of close reasons without actually having to open the flag dialog.

Comment: @BSMP One more good reason. I'm often do so on a different question, just to get close reasons again, well for primary close reasons, that's not really necessary to open the dialogue on a different question just for copying the information.

Comment: This issue has shown up in a different guise in [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307197/2751851). Much of the guidance being offered to the OP boils down to "you shouldn't answer questions that fit one of the standard close reasons", but that is a bit of a tall order when you are under 3k and there is no convenient reference for the close reasons.

Answer (score 7):

It's there, just not in the on topic article.  From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Opinion questions (more description about what goes and what doesn't in the article):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
>   avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Too broad (same article near the top):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: Ah, nice to see, but at least an explicit link would be nice, since we're closing off-topic and that's what the OP sees primarily.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The too broad close reason links [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) which states: "too broad: if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format "

Comment: It's nice to see that information is available in the help center, but it should be concentrated at off-topic, consistently with the proposed close reasons.