# Should we avoid answering questions with a negative score?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

If I find a simple mistake in the low quality question posted by a low reputation beginner, should I answer it or not?

Since code in comments is not readable, a better solution is to submit the solution as an answer rather than a comment. Since the post has a low quality, the question is getting downvoted very fast and reaches a score of -5 or below.

What should I do with these types of questions?

Does answering low quality post affect my reputation in the future?

Are negatively scored questions (with an on hold status) even with accepted answers going to be deleted in future?

Note: Some members are even downvoting actual answers to the problem along with the question.

Comment: I often answer off-topic questions that are likely to get closed in a comment. There is nothing wrong with doing that.

Comment: Some members are even down voting actual answer to the problem along with the question.

Comment: _Does answering low quality post effects my reputation in future?_ Directly? No. [That particular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891403/java-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-scanner-closed/32891528#32891528) was off topic because it was a typo. Just vote to close (when you can). We gave the answer in a comment. The question should just be deleted.

Comment: You can mark an answer community wiki to avoid rep loss through downvotes. But with really bad questions, it is better to answer in comments, if at all - also to allow speedy deletion

Comment: Part of the problem of answering these questions in an actual answer is that the answer will absolutely be correct, and it's very likely someone will upvote it. Once that happens, the question will not be automatically deleted, and will instead require delete votes from several 10k+ rep users to delete the completely useless question. If you feel compelled to answer a typo question, do so in a comment, and don't forget to close vote.

Comment: If the post isn't off topic and just needs improvement, you can always edit the question to fix it before answering.

If the Asker just has a typo in their code it's better to stick with making a comment. As you point out, some users will down vote answers to off-topic posts. If putting the code in a comment makes it too hard to read, you could just describe the typo instead: "You forgot the semicolon on line 25" or "You forgot to initialize your Foo object".

Comment: [Downvoting good answers on bad questions, helpful or not?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274919/downvoting-good-answers-on-bad-questions-helpful-or-not)

Comment: Don't answer bad questions. That is generally a horrible idea that makes the jobs of those active in moderating and maintaining the quality of Q&A on this site much harder. Because now, instead of the question being closed and deleted automatically, your probably correct answer will get upvoted or accepted which would cause those people to have to go to greater lengths to get the question deleted. Unless you can adequately edit the question into shape. Otherwise please just leave it alone.

Comment: _"Unless you can adequately edit the question into shape"_ -- exactly. This is the basis for the answer I posted below.

Comment: Another scenario is that you might genuinely disagree with the downvotes, in which case it is obviously okay to answer. (That is admittedly unlikely given a question which "is getting downvoted very fast and reaches a score of -5 or below", though.)

Comment: Question Score is 0 when I answer. It became -5 within minutes. My answer down voted from 1 to -1 later. Before answer, I did not expect that down vote will happen to that extent.

Comment: @sunrise76 The number of downvotes doesn't really matter. I just mentioned it because a disagreement seems less likely at -5 than at -1; still, one might conceivably think that all of the five downvotes are nonsensical anyway. In any case, there is a general rule based on something more clear-cut: don't answer questions to which one of the [standard close reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) apply. If the question looks salvageable, try to improve it by editing or engaging with the asker via comments; otherwise, downvote and (once you reach 3k) vote to close as appropriate.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, there is something wrong with that. It just encourages that user to continue coming here and asking off-topic questions.

Comment: Well definitely don't answer in comments, whatever else you do. @Pekka your behaviour is extremely disappointing for someone so prominent!! Comments are _absolutely not_ the place for answers or anything looking like answers, under any circumstances ever. Claiming that "it is better to answer in comments" in any situation whatsoever is reprehensibly wrong and irresponsible.

Comment: Questions with a big negative score make me twitch because the kleptomaniac in me wants to give a brilliant answer in the hope of one day getting the coveted `Reversal` badge. But at the same time I do agree with the SO stance on bad questions plus I know the reversal is singularly unlikely to happen anyway... but all the same, gah! must.... resist.... answering....!

Comment: I think you shouldn't answer low quality questions from low rep users. The reason is that it gives the wrong message. It's like telling those users it's ok to turn to SO without putting any efford in it themselves. Why bother trying when someone on SO will give you the answer anyway?

Comment: @Lightness Meh. If a question is decent but off topic (which is easy to do on SO these days) there is nothing wrong with pointing the asker in the right direction. Sometimes, it is even okay to point a complete newb asking a bad question in the right direction. Just make it clear that the question isn't welcome in its current form and that they should check out the guidelines first.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Surely, "answering" an off-topic question albeit in the comments merely satisfies the OP and gives them literally zero incentive to follow the rules next time. If they know they will get their question answered despite closure, what incentive do they have to improve their approach when they next have an off-topic question? I think perhaps you underestimate the selfishness of OPs!!

Answer (score 46):

The thing that Stack Overflow is trying to accomplish is collating *good* answers.

A good answer is one that in future, people will be able to visit the site, read, and find useful.

But it's really hard to write a good answer to a shoddy question.

It's not completely impossible, it's just unlikely. That's why - generally - we vote to close/delete/down vote bad questions. Not because we don't like the person asking them, or because we're mean - but because the question isn't likely to contribute an opportunity for a *good* answer.

One of the ongoing problems of this sort of site is that of the [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). A person who shows up, wants a solution to the immediate problem, and then will disappear again... until next time they need a solution. That's not a problem in and of itself, but it does clutter the site with junk - questions and answers that are of no use but to the supplicant.

So within that context - if you think you can genuinely contribute something that:

- Will be found, based on the starting question.
- Will remain valuable because it offers some useful insight.

Then answer away.

However if all you're doing is feeding a help vampire, then think twice - by doing so you encourage them to repeat their behaviour, never improving their question asking style (because being shoddy works well enough) and filling up the site with questions - and answers - that are just noise, and will just obfuscate the 'good stuff'.

You *may* find your answer disappears later (when the question gets deleted) - and whatever rep you earned goes away. (This also applies to blatantly off-topic posts.)

You may also find people down vote you, because they don't approve of feeding help vampires. (It's partially to discourage them, partially to discourage you.)

I will often offer a conciliatory comment-answer. Usually referring to either how to improve the question such that it's better, or to the appropriate point of reference (e.g which instance of TFM it would be beneficial to R). I recognise this isn't always the best idea, but call it a bit of a compromise - my desire to be helpful, against perpetuating vampirism.

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone is qualified to decide which questions are useful for future visitors and which are not otherwise we could replace the downvote button with a delete button that works for anybody who can post an answer. Answers should be judged only based on their own quality -- if it is a good answer; it is a good answer whether the corresponding question is asked by a help vampire or not. Making decisions assuming you know the future is dangerous (it reminds me of thought police and witch trials where decisions are made based on conviction alone without facts to support them).

Comment: Moderation isn't  "thought police" or "witch trials". It's cleaning your house.  You don't leave your cat litter tray overflowing because you don't know the future, and it might be useful - you throw it out because it smells. We have a voting system to deal with borderline cases. A heftily downvoted post has been heftily downvoted because multiple people thought it was rubbish.

Comment: Wisdom of a crowd may fail. We wouldn't burn people at the stake for the hundreds of years if it weren't popular. I don't understand how "negative score" became "it is a help vampire question, all help vampire questions are bad, let's downvote everything and delete them". Explicitly advising people to downvote good answers only because the question has a negative score is despicable. It does not make the internet a better place.

Comment: .... uuh, it didn't? People can downvote questions for whatever reason they choose. The tooltip suggests: "This question is does not show any research effort; it us unclear or not useful". On answers - "this answer is not useful". It is down to the voter what "useful" means.  A number of those decide that "useful" means "in the broader context of Stack Overflow" rather than "solving the problem for this requestor". 
And yes - wisdom of a crowd may fail. Democracy is a pretty pathetic system, it's just the least bad that's been tried so far.

Comment: While I agree by and large, I do often answer "vampire" questions in ways that FORCE them to do their own work. It helps people who find it later, gets the question off the unanswered list, and helps short-circuit the parasitic behavior of *Programmaticus Nogooglus*.

Comment: If you really want to frame this in a way that focuses on the merit of the content and not how the author is perceived, you'll stop using epithets like "help vampire."

Comment: it is one thing to allow people to vote for whatever even misguided reasons  but validating wrong voting patterns or even encouraging them is a different thing. Here's specific example: [a question with a negative score that has a good answer](http://goo.gl/EGjoX7) that did help me (I needed big-O cost for gcd(a,b) and it gave the answer:  `O(log(min(a,b))`). I don't care why the question is downvoted: I found it via google and I have the same question and it provides the answer -- I'm happy. If we encourage to downvote such answers then they might be deleted by some cleaning up process.

Comment: @Air: It's convenient to have a quick, easily-understood term, rather than having to repeat the definition of "help vampire" every time you want to refer to this growing and oft-seen group of people. It's perfectly acceptable, since the quality of the content of help vampires is directly attributable to what they are. You'll find it easier to understand answers like this if you spend less time being offended for others.

Comment: Of relevance: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire - it's like "don't feed the troll" - they're getting what they want if you do, so they will continue doing it. Part of the reason we have a rep mechanism is because it provides a feedback loop to encourage good, and discourage bad. This doesn't apply if you're not interested in site participation, but getting your work done for you. Which is why we have things like question bans etc. But you will see a pretty steady stream still of this sort of thing despite that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit One problem with "help vampire" is that it switches the focus from the quality of the question to the mindset of the person who is asking it. Are we against *the question* because it's non-useful, or are we against *the person* because we're offended that someone is "taking advantage" of us? To me, the phrase "help vampire" implies the latter. If it's the former, more accurate sobriquets might be "nonsensicals" or "one-offs" or "hyper-specifics" - that is, what's the quality of the question which we don't like, rather than the attitude of the person asking?

Comment: Fortunately, you can also see people's positing history and previous comments and answer acceptance.  That makes it considerably easier to tell the difference. I wouldn't for one minute suggest it should be default, but there are very definitely people who try to outsource to SO. Who are clearly not interested in learning or contributing, but trying to get a free coding service.  This behaviour is reinforced by rep whoring.

Comment: @R.M.: While it's encouraged to focus on the content rather than the poster, and rightly so, speaking more generally we _do_ also want to educate and in order to do that you have to at least admit to yourself that there are ultimately human beings writing these posts, and each human being has traits and habits. In order to educate, you have to be aware of and relate to those traits.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with the basic thoughts behind the answer posted by Sobrique. That said, I'd like to offer some additional advice:

I definitely agree that one should try to avoid answering bad questions, for the reasons stated in the other answer. But, the word "bad" encompasses so many different possibilities that that approach is at best a broad rule of thumb.

If you do feel that you can usefully answer the question, that means you've seen something in the question that others have not. This can happen, generally because you have more expertise in the topic and/or have run into the particular issue or misunderstanding the OP is trying to describe.

But the question might still be a bad question in some way. Sobrique's answer suggests only answer if your answer "will be found, based on the starting question". I'll offer an alternative: yes, it's important that your answer can be found by those needing it. But remember that you can edit other people's questions.

So it's not so important that the "starting question" itself is good. What matters if whether you can *make it good*. If you feel you can answer the question, then you may be (and probably are) in a unique position to also improve the question. In fact, I would say that if you feel you're able to usefully answer a question that is otherwise considered bad by the community and intend to go ahead and do so, that you should consider yourself *obligated* to also edit the question. That way, you are in fact answering a *good* question (*).

Doing so will reveal in the question the elements that you yourself were able to perceive even as others could not, as well as will fix other issues that likely exist with the question, including grammar and formatting errors, but also even including a lack of a good code example. This will not only make the question more searchable, in making it more comprehensible it may lead to allowing other good answers to the question as well, complementing your own.

As Sobrique's pointed out, the broader goal of SO is not so much to help individual people asking questions (though that's an important secondary goal), but rather to maintain and curate as large a collection as possible of searchable, useful questions and answers. That goal is only half-achieved if all you do is answer a bad question. The rest of the goal requires that the bad question be turned into a good question.

(*) Unfortunately, SO doesn't have a mechanism for notifying downvoters that a question has been edited and may no longer warrant the downvote. So such questions always will have its early history dragging it down. But that is IMHO not a reason to avoid trying to improve the question.

Comment: This. One of my top answer in SO was posted on -5 question which then had been closed. After editing the question to clarify the problem, the question (now) is not in negative score, which might be the best experience in my SE life (though I won't get reversal badge :p).

Comment: This is quite handy for keeping track of down voted questions. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackeye/pihfndpmcafdecheofkjfkadecoogigm?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

No. The negative score may not be deserved, or the question could be improved, sometimes with a simple edit to the title.

In many cases the questioner doesn't know the *specific* reason that their code is not working. But you spot it and write a great answer for it.

In that case you can make the question relevant and useful just by changing the title from "Why is this broken?" to "Why does writing too much into a string make malloc fail?". Often this causes it to become a duplicate, but not always.

Comment: Sometimes one or two people wrongly downvoted, because they read too fast and assumed some mistake on the part of OP, or are not fully familiar with the problem/technologies mentioned and assume the OP needs some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

As a younger user of StackOverflow, I'd like to add that the negative response I've gotten as a beginner on this site has been quite disheartening. Whenever I was first picking up a language, and couldn't figure something out, I'd come to stackoverflow and ask for help. Some people were very understanding of my beginner status, but others would just down vote my questions and not provide any help.

I've still learned a lot about posting effective questions, but the community reaction to my lack of knowledge was quite hurtful. The next time you see a very basic question being posted on StackOverFlow, know that there's a good chance that the poster is just a young person trying to get through their school Computer Science class.

Comment: I just down voted this answer because the question isn't about voting behavior of users and the side effect that might have. As such your post doesn't help solving the issue the OP has. The topic you try to discuss has seen some posts before. You might want to do some research on that to get an idea about the general idea the community about that topic.

Comment: I up voted this answer because I believe the reverse. The basic question was, 'If I find a downvoted question should I answer it".  The answer is yes, in my opinion young people who ask questions, regardless of simplicity deserve an answer, and if the question is worded poorly, often a few simple edits will resolve the issue.  Down votes I've witnessed happen quite quickly and without any truly 'valid' reason ... imho.

Comment: _"Whenever I was first picking up a language, and couldn't figure something out, I'd come to stackoverflow and ask for help"_ -- except that basic language questions are almost never good questions for Stack Overflow, as they can almost always be answered better by documentation, language references, and even existing SO questions, all of which you can easily find with your favorite search engine. In any case, I see only 7 questions posted by you, just 1 with a negative score, and that one was properly closed by SO users (IMHO it is "too broad" rather than "unclear", but whatever).

Comment: _"the community reaction to my lack of knowledge was quite hurtful"_ -- no, it wasn't. You _perceived_ it in a way that caused you to feel hurt. But no one was actually trying to hurt you. They are simply trying to maintain a high level of quality on Stack Overflow. I readily grant it is often difficult for the younger or less-experienced to grasp the difference, but it's a very important difference to learn, as is learning to take objective, professional criticism without perceiving it as a personal attack.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "IMHO it is 'too broad' rather than 'unclear', but whatever" -- There is one way in which the close reason really matters in this case. Assuming there were no deleted comments, why didn't any of those who chose "unclear what you are asking" leave a comment asking for clarification? A more concrete illustration of what Karina was thinking of would likely have been enough to avoid closure, or at least to locate some useful duplicate. The sort of trigger-happy moderation that seems to have taken place there is unnecessarily abrasive.

Comment: @duplode: _"why didn't any of those who chose "unclear what you are asking" leave a comment asking for clarification"_ -- unfortunately, the same kinds of humans asking questions are also involved in answering, voting, etc. I.e. just as askers sometimes are too lazy to review the help topics concerning what makes a good question, voters are sometimes too lazy to explain their vote (or to be charitable, may sometimes feel the vote itself is explanation enough). I'm not saying it's ideal, but it's a bit hypocritical of a lazy asker to complain about a lazy voter. :)

Comment: @duplode: sorry if the previous comment seems glib. I don't mean it to be...I just mean that to some extent, these issues such as they are, are basic human nature. Answerers and voters aren't necessarily any more immune to the issues than are questioners.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Human nature indeed, but if that isn't a good excuse for askers it isn't for moderators either. If anything, those who take up moderation on their own accord should ramp up their efforts to keep natural inclinations under control. Also, asking a vague first question does not imply laziness. The question we are talking about, for instance, is far from being a "debug this for me" or "write my homework" request.

Comment: @duplode: _"it isn't for moderators either"_ -- no disagreement from me there. I'm not trying to defend them. And I agree that they should set a better example, if nothing else then so that the lazy questioner can learn from that example. _"asking a vague first question does not imply laziness"_ -- we'll agree to disagree there, I think. The laziness to which I refer is the lack of making oneself familiar with the standards of questioning; the help topic guidance is pretty clear about why vague questions don't work, so someone that misses the mark so widely just didn't read that guidance.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "we'll agree to disagree there, I think. [...]" -- I concede you that point. Still, my laziness and yours are indeed quite different from each other. Some questions will never become good questions, and some askers will never bother to write questions fit for SO; others, however, will if nudged towards the right direction. I feel it is important to recognise the difference, and handle incoming questions accordingly.