# They ask, I answer, they delete. What can I do? And what should I have done?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I just had an experience very much like the one described in [I answered a question, he accepted it, and then he deleted the question!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281399/i-answered-a-question-he-accepted-it-and-then-he-deleted-the-question)

I saw [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33633369/1983854) that looked a bit broad, but not extremely bad. After asking for clarification and getting some I decided to go on and answer, since some knowledge could be gained from it. The OP was a brand new user, so I had to go on and on asking for clarifications for a while. Nicely, we finally got the solution and the problem was solved. Hurray!

To my surprise, not very long after saying that that my answer works, the user deleted the whole question leaving myself with a dirty feeling of having been used : )

Is there anything I can do? Should I foresee these help vampires?

Comment: Something smells fishy.  They explicitly thanked you, *then* deleted the question.  Perhaps they wanted to avoid being caught by someone?

Comment: Some new users don't realize that the questions are for the future. Pretty sure if you flag for mod attention and explain the situation, it will be undeleted. (Or it likely will from meta effect now that you've posted this.)

Comment: @Kendra:  This is one of those weird Meta-effect scenarios:  the question would likely be undeleted, but the question itself is unclear and poorly worded, so it *may* wind up being closed and/or deleted again.

Comment: OK, it's undeleted.

Comment: @Makoto I couldn't tell. :) Guess I really should work on getting up to 10k if I want to see these things before they're undeleted!

Comment: Funny, I watched that whole thing go down. That question came up in the review queue, I downvoted and was typing up a comment when you guys started commenting back and forth.

Comment: @enki.dev yes I in fact casted initially a vote to close as "too broad" but then started seeing it a bit clearer.

Comment: I've edited the question; perhaps now it will be seen in a better light by users.

Comment: @TylerH yours is a very good edit. Now the question shines : )

Comment: In my impression, "help vampire" seems not refer to scenarios that delete questions after getting answers described above.

Comment: @amuse it depends really. Someone who is selfish enough to just delete a question to get rid of downvotes certainly has HV tendencies. Its all about me-me-me. It doesn't look like a question asked by a student who then wants to cover their tracks.

Comment: Sounds like a homework-cheater trying to cover her/his tracks.

Comment: Some people treat support forums like their own personal conversation with the person at the other end. On our product support forum we often had people ask a question, and then when it was answered they would edit the original post, remove the original question and ask something completely different (or just replace it with "Thanks!"). Very strange behavior. Eventually we just disabled editing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Odd that *your* question hasn't received an answer, given that judging from the comments above several people obviously have useful insight to share. Well, comments on Meta are AFAIK rarely if ever purged, but for posterity's sake even so…

> Is there anything I can do?

A detailed flag on the question for the moderator is one thing you can try. Especially if the scenario is blatant, where the OP has posted a comment that *clearly* states that your answer did in fact address their question usefully (e.g. "thanks! your answer worked!" or some such), I would expect a moderator would gladly undelete the question. Just be sure to explain clearly in the flag what happened, including the comment.

Another option, as you've found, is to round up community members and ask them (directly or indirectly) to help by voting to undelete the question. You can do this with a Meta post (as here) or in a relevant chat room, for example.

In either case, IMHO it is important to consider the value of the question. [We should not always answer questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307197/should-we-avoid-answering-questions-with-a-negative-score/), as poorly-written questions are hard for others to find in searches and may confuse those who do find them, even if there are any good answers posted for the question. If you find a poorly-written question that you *can* answer, and believe it could be useful, then [you should edit the question to improve it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307228); ensure that the question is as comprehensible to everyone else as it was to you, if not more so.

Fortunately, all of the above has been done in this case. So your immediate problem was solved before you even received an actual answer to the question. :)

> Should I foresee these help vampires?

*"Nobody expects the Inqui^H^H^H^H^H Help Vampire!"*

Seriously though, no. How could you foresee anything like that, except on a probability basis? Certainly help vampires tend to have the worst questions. Composition is bad, grammar is bad, formatting is bad, code example is bad, etc. But these are just clues. There are badly written questions by well-intentioned and conscientious people, and there are probably even help vampires out there who can put a complete grammatically correct sentence together.

There is nothing you can do in advance to know whether someone is actually going to turn out to be a help vampire. All you can do is assume the best, and not let it get to you if something goes wrong.

*(By the way: extrapolating from the first several pages of my answers it looks to me as though roughly 10% of my answers received *zero* feedback from the OP; no votes up or down, nor an "accept". Now, I grant that at least some of those, maybe I goofed and the OP was too nice to give me an honest downvote when they should have. But I'll bet that at least half of those were genuinely useful answers, for which the OP just ignored.*

Frankly, a 5% rate of failure of original posters seems pretty good to me, in the context of the Internet. Just goes to show how Stack Overflow actually does a pretty good job encouraging good behavior :) )

Comment: We are the [Unsung Heroes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero)

Comment: Very nice and useful answer, thanks a lot.... Oh damn I cannot delete my question now :D

Comment: @Tas: indeed. Though, it turns out I think I may have missed my window of opportunity for that badge. When I browse through the list of people who have it, they are generally relatively lower-rep users with a small enough number of answers that the law of averages hasn't caught up with them yet. I.e. the badge requires a full 25% of one's answers be zero-score accepted answers, but given that way more than 75% of SO users understand that accepted answers are usually also useful, with a large enough sample size, getting to 25% is just very improbable.

Answer (score -26):

They do this, because after the answer gets an upvote, or the question has at least two answers, they aren't able to delete it any more.

It results in their questions getting downvotes, close votes, etc, and they won't be able to delete it.

Most of the question deleters fear only from this phenomenon.

Stack Exchange is hard for anybody not knowing its rules well enough.

This phenomenon is only the result of many years of uncontrolled newbie harassment so common on this site.

---

Note: A solution would be if the OPs could delete their questions only if it was deeply downvoted. I don't hope that the Stack Exchange will do anything in this direction.

Comment: The good folks that try to help posters, in turn, are [harassed as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39928562/2564301).

Comment: @RadLexus No, I am thinking on goodstanding newbie questions getting good quality and meaningful questions. Also they are harassed a lot here, without any meaningful reason. Your example is a bad example, because it is a bad question, what deserves the downs.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand your point. Not every "newbie" barges in on Stack Overflow and drops his homework question - I have seen lots of insightful good questions from new users. "New to SO" does **not** equal "new to programming"! I cannot recall a single occasion where a *good* question got downvoted *because* it came from a new user.

Comment: @RadLexus I can... I can.

Comment: So there are hordes of innocent, blameless askers, who are carefully exploiting the precise rules (can delete question with one answer; can't with two) and the differences of opinion between different groups of SO users (is this question worth answering or not?) in order to get answers without leaving any trace to be criticized, yet are only doing so because they've been misunderstood in the past and don't know the rules very well. Certainly not because they just want an answer for themselves and don't care tuppence for SO's goal of shared reference material.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think it would be a good filter to allow asking questions only after the OPs have some upvoted answers. From example, binding the "ask question" privilege to a very minimal reputation (2?). And, if a question is deeply downvoted, the OP *should be allowed to delete it*. And, if there is an ask-del misuse, the 10k+ users should be able to undelete the question. Banning the OP from asking new questions is a bad solution, they are new users so they lose nothing by registering a new account and continuing the same behavior.

Comment: @peterh: Well, MSE did experiment with requiring 2 rep for questions; even there, the one site most likely to work (arguably), there were problems, and the requirement was removed as soon as the flood of off-topic questions ceased.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ok. So, there is the problem of the sticked questions, i.e. if your question got some downs, but you can't delete it because it has already an upvoted answer. And as time goes, it gets newer and newer downs, and you can't do anything. The only possibility to avoid this problem if you delete your question on the spot after it got the first answer.

Comment: @peterh: "I might get downvoted by people who think they know the site better than me, but I know they're wrong to do so, so I'm going to prevent them from doing that by wiping everything out as soon as I've gotten what I need" is a distinctly arrogant, anti-intellectual, and self-centered attitude that I don't think is worth us enabling.

Comment: @NathanTuggy No. "I made a bad question, I would be glad to delete it but they don't allow to clean my name" <- this is what they see from that, and they are right. If a question is deeply downvoted, the OP should be allowed to delete it, only to clean his name. If the question is not downvoted (or not deeply), the 10k+ users should be allowed to revert an ask-del misuse by undelete votes. So simple is it, and I am absolutely not surprised that nobody wants even to try to understand it.

Comment: @peterh, if they have learned from their early questions, they most likely have a high enough score by now that it doesn't really matter if they get downvoted. They might try editing their question to at least fix up the formatting and content as much as possible to stave off some downvotes _even if the question is fundamentally flawed_. How do we keep quality high, though, if no one moderates anything? Not only that, my 3 questions I now feel are fundamentally flawed, but they didn't get even a single downvote.

Comment: If you ever feel that ashamed of a question, you can unlink it from your username: [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/209901).

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you very much! It helps in my case. But, afaik, I knew this possibility only after years of SE experience, I think most of the new users don't know it, and thus asking from a different account, and deleting the question on the spot after the first, is still a working defensive strategy for them, against the sticked questions. Note, I absolutely don't feel myself ashamed by my downvoted meta questions, and the revenge downs on the main sites weren't enough hard for that until now. I only notice the phenomenon, and produce further good, but deeply downvoted meta posts.

Comment: @oldtechaa Editing old questions helps only a little bit, an edit doesn't produce enough attention. The main problem with it that they still can see as the newer and newer downs are coming and they can't do anything. It is a *very unpleasant* experience for a new user, and honestly I can absolutely understand that they start this harmful behavior. Once I did with my [this](https://serverfault.com/q/634188/200053) (ok, on serverfault) sticked question, that I initiated its closure many times to attract attention. It wasn't closed, but in around 3 tries I collected enough ups to compensate.

Comment: @oldtechaa I simply didn't know that I could ask the team to disassociate from my account. From the same reason, I played this ask-del behavior on the meta SE for a while (although I deleted the question only if its first vote was a down). [Note: the downs wasn't removed even for the attracted attention, only new ups came.] I think, at least this disassociation mechanism should be an automatized and a better known possibility for sticked questions.

Comment: @peterh, let me explain what I meant. To downvote, a person must have come upon the question somehow. Now that person can either come upon a fundamentally flawed question with good formatting or the same with bad formatting; which do you think they'll downvote? We don't downvote (in most cases) for a question that shows reasonable effort but still doesn't understand a simple problem. We downvote based on how hard people tried. The fact that edits do not attract attention matters little; what matters is people found my question, how can I keep them from downvoting?

Comment: Also note that in many cases, peoples' downvotes have become permanent due to the amount of time that has passed. This underscores the reason why you should always make your post the best it can be _when you post it_.

Comment: @oldtechaa Although I can only partially agree your reasoning, the problem of the sticked questions, at least for the people not knowing their ordinary solution, still lives. Your reasoning is an explanation, why the downs remain even after the question is fixed, and I can partially agree that (I think, the probably unsaid reason, about the sparing of the time of the voters, is also agreeable to me), the sticked question problem still exist and motivates semi-legal, and sometimes harmful behaviors, while it could be solved on technical methods ("disassociate my question" link/button).

Comment: @oldtechaa Furthermore, the problem is not only that it motivates bad behaviors, it is also a problem that having a sticked question makes the SE significantly un-enjoyable. Getting the downs again and again (or having a bad question to what you can't do anything) is simply not funny, not enjoyable, it is a... problem. People visit a site not for begging to the admins to remove/dissociate their bad questions, and not for checking how many downs have arrived today. They visit the site because they like to get answers, solve interesting problems and collect reputation, this is the funny.