# Should I warn potential answerers that an OP has a history of erasing (probably homework) questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I just noticed the question [How to prove asymptotic upper and lower bound using only induction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936738/how-to-prove-asymptotic-upper-and-lower-bound-using-only-induction) by some user.

A few minutes prior to his/her posting, the user deleted a [question which I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935811/finding-an-algorithm-and-the-correctness-and-runtime-for-such/39936063); his/her last comment on the answer, just before doing so, was

> Thank you very much. I hope I can learn these questions and be able to answer in the way you did.

I flagged the previous deleted question, but my guess is that anyone answering the new question will just waste time, as the question will be deleted by the OP immediately afterwards (possibly to avoid detection as homework problems).

What is the right way to warn potential answerers of the new question?

1. Should I write a comment below the question, warning people that their answers will likely be deleted? That doesn't feel right.
2. Should I flag the new question as well? It seems strange to flag something that didn't happen yet.
3. Should I amend the existing flag? I can't figure out how to do so.
4. Perhaps it's just none of my business? If someone answers, it's between them and the OP.

Comment: 5. We can undelete it.

Comment: Looking at the track record of this user, I doubt you have to suffer him for much longer.

Comment: 6. After undeletion, we can upvote your answer so that the user no longer can delete it again ;)

Comment: Consider yourself warned - answering zero-effort "do my homework" questions comes with good chance of loosing your work to question deletion (either by community or OP). I think everyone else already well aware of it and plan accordingly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The fear from this phenomenon results that new users get answers only rarely. Note, all what you put here, has a license what actually *enables* the SE to not allow to delete it.

Comment: @peterh sounds like a good behavior to me. New users frequently post homework assignments to get it done for free (instead of using existing pay-for-homework services that can be found easily https://www.bing.com/search?q=do+my+homework) - such questions often downvoted as "no research", closed as "too broad" due to amount of guidance needed for proper answer and should not be answered on SO. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: bizarrely, some people call these attempts to keep up the spirit of SO ["newbie harassment"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335932/2564301).

Comment: _@Ami_ Just a heads up: Keep on what you're doing. I mostly achieved that positively. Though you might need to refrain answering some kind of trivial questions (or easy to find duplicates). I already invited you to participate in the SOCVR room I think. Close voting and deleting crap is probably the better reaction for some kind of questions. You're welcome to ask and discuss.

Comment: Hard to find fault with anybody warning other users they are about to waste their free time.  But the site owners don't like it and prefer you use the institutionalized methods, they generate less crap in their email inbox that nobody wants to read and nobody can answer.  You can downvote and you can pick *anything* from the close dialog.  It doesn't have to be accurate, everybody knows that your preferred choice is not on there.  We won't hold it against you.

Comment: Relevant: [Statistics on answered questions deleted by their author](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313854/4639281)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> 1. Should I write a comment below the question, warning people that their answers will likely be deleted? That doesn't feel right.

*"That doesn't feel right."* Your guts are telling you well.

> 2. Should I flag the new question as well? It seems strange to flag something that didn't happen yet.

No, each case needs to be handled individually based on the content, not from knowing a users bad behavior.

> 3. Should I amend the existing flag? I can't figure out how to do so.

See my answer at point 2.

> 4. Perhaps it's just none of my business? If someone answers, it's between them and the OP.

It's about the resulting content, and judging if that would be useful for future research or not.

---

I've been adding points 5. and 6. as possible reactions.

But honestly, if an OP keeps that behavior you disclosed, they'll not survive long at Stack Overflow. Most likely they'll going to be question banned soon.

Comment: `they'll not survive long at Stack Overflow.` What about sockpuppets?

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent These may lead to an IP ban as soon identified and proven for bad behavior (voting frauds or such).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Undeleted.

Comment: And now deleted....

Comment: @Braiam but presumably for the right reasons this time? (hopefully)

Comment: @Jeutnarg at the end, it was just a waste of moderating efforts for something OP could have solved. Close voters and delete voters had 1 vote less when the situation basically resolved itself, not counting the time and mental strain trying to read that question...

Comment: @Braiam Letting the OP delete is just disrespectful to any answering user though. Not good behavior,

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ disrespectful is to ask those kind of question. OP on the other hand was *naive* (?) enough to answer it... and then he suffered the consequences of its naivety.

Answer (score 24):

Maybe I should offer another point of view:

OP deleted the question, but since you can see deleted posts, and you know what you just wrote, you could ask the same question, but with a better title, MCVE, use case, etc. and answer that question. You can have the cake and eat it too! With the plus that your answer is under a question that lives up to your answer.

BTW, deleting questions with answers seems to count for the question ban... so don't worry, these guys wouldn't be asking many questions for long.

Comment: Note, I'm not saying that you should answer these questions, you should not... just that you don't have to feel so bitter about the asker deleting their question with your answer along.

Comment: People may have wide range of feelings when they figured that they  helped someone to cheat... :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov from my point of view, I'm only worried about content... what people do with the knowledge they have has always been a problem, but restricting the access to knowledge has been worse.

Comment: Now that the question has been undeleted and I can see all the gore it's... I prefer it deleted and closed...

Comment: _If the question (and answer) are worth keeping_, I prefer to undelete it & upvote the answer to prevent re-deletion. That makes it easier for teachers who search SO for evidence of homework cheats. Otherwise, if the answer is good (and not a dupe) doing a self-answered question is a great idea.

Comment: @PM2Ring as I said, I prefer not to answer such questions, my time is more valuable

Comment: **You can have the cake and eat it too!** :)

Comment: @mtk Yes, but you can't eat the cake and have it, too.