# A suggested solution to new users deleting their questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, post-ban, rules, vote-to-undelete

### The problem

[They ask, I answer, they delete. What can I do? And what should I have done?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309896/1783163)

[I answered a question, he accepted it, and then he deleted the question!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281399/1783163)

[Should I warn potential answerers that an OP has a history of erasing (probably homework) questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335930/1783163)

---

Some new accounts display the following harmful behavior:

- They ask a question; then
- After they've got the first answer, they delete it on the spot and disappear.

This removes potentially-valuable content and the reputation that could have been associated with it.

### The reason

I think this happens because questions can be deleted by the OP only while they don't have an upvoted answer, or multiple answers. After the first upvoted answer, even the OP can't delete it, even if the question is deeply downvoted. The result is that the question continues to collect downvotes and the OP can't do anything with it.

After having this happen to a few questions, what will the OP do?

1. Delete or simply abandon the account; or
2. Register a new one, and continue the same behavior with it.

### Why the current solution isn't effective

The current solution is to ban them from asking new questions. But if their account is new, they lose nothing by deleting or simply abandoning it and continuing the harmful behavior on a new one, while the content they created and later deleted remains deleted.

By choosing this strategy, they've already given up the possibility of ever collecting a high reputation on the site. The automatic question ban doesn't worsen this state, thus it doesn't have any motivation and has no effect on the already-deleted content.

### Proposed solution of the problem

Instead, I suggest that:

1. If a question is deeply downvoted, its OP should be allowed to delete it, even if it has an upvoted answer, if only to defend their name/reputation. (Currently, questions can be deleted by their OPs until they don't have an upvoted answer, or multiple answers.)
2. If the question isn't downvoted (or not too deeply), but there is an misuse, the 10k+ (or 20k+) users should be able to undelete the deleted question by undelete votes. (Questions deleted by their OP can be undeleted currently only by mod intervention.)

---

Everything that we post here has a license that enables SE to hold it in perpetuity, even against our will. This is why the rules can deny the OP the right to delete their content, even if it is deeply downvoted.

From the other side, what is allowed to exist on its sites is up to the SE. Thus the rules have a freedom in delete/undelete matters in both directions. Thus the wishes or rights of the OPs aren't really relevant here, only the rules of SE count, and thus this suggestion isn't in an intellectual property frame. It is a suggestion to a friendly and useful approach for everybody.

Furthermore, it would require only a minimal change in the SE software. The behavior of the SE in these years shows, minimal changes to the SE software have a low chance to be ever implemented, while major changes have a negligible chance. Thus requests for a software change should suggest a minimal change.

Comment: Any improvement to this proposal, particularly grammar/spelling corrections, are welcomed.

Comment: Why do you think that is the reason? I'd guess most new users are unaware that their question can't be deleted once an answer gets upvoted. *"Questions deleted by their OP can be undeleted currently only by mod intervention"* - I don't think that's true, is it?

Comment: I can't stop wondering on the reading speed of my first downvoters for the reading and understanding the whole proposal in a half minute, and knowing that it is not useful. If you do the same on the main site, you serve as an additional proof behind "The reason" section of the proposal.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe it is not their first account... after having even a *single* sticked question, the obvious reaction is to ask all of your new questions on newly created accounts.

Comment: I don’t understand what problem we are solving here. The problem of users asking and deleting right away should be relatively minimal because of the 1-upvote rule. No?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I described the problem in the first section of the proposal. This problem could be solved by the proposal.

Comment: But the problem already has a solution: if there’s at least one answer with at least one upvote, the user can’t delete their question any more. Is this turning out  not to be a sufficient solution?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Because it leads to the ask-del misuse, as it was described in the proposal very clearly.

Comment: @peterh I don't see that this is a real problem. Of course there are always some users who delete their question for various reasons right away after they get answered, but I don't see that this is a real issue on the site and I also don't see how your proposal should improve anything.

Comment: @peterh *Is* there actually widespread such misuse, though? Do you have any evidence supporting that? I realize it’s very difficult to come by *hard* evidence to anyone without access to the database, but there’s got to be *something* more than just your assertion that there’s a problem.

Comment: Isn't the problem that people insist on answering crap questions, making it more likely that the Q will be downvoted and the OP will delete it? That can't be solved by letting the OP delete it in more cases. And as I understand it there are systems in place to identify users who create new accounts to get around a ban.

Comment: I don’t disagree that there’s cases where it would be fair to allow the OP to delete their question - but that should really be a case for moderator intervention rather than an automated feature.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Mods won't intervent if the deletion would destroy the reputation of the answerers, and also interventing in non-exceptional case isn't their task.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you very much the English corrections. But, please stop removing the capital titles from the proposal, it significantly worsens it comprehensibility.

Comment: So what is the concrete change you're proposing? How *"deeply"* does a question have to be down voted for this to kick in? How many current questions would be eligible for deletion if this were applied now? How many of those have any upvoted (and therefore valuable) answers, rather than just multiple FGIW-ers with zero- or down-voted answers? (Also I disagree that adding titles is the solution to a broader lack of comprehensibility, but you do you.)

Comment: @peterh `Mods won't intervent if the deletion would destroy the reputation of the answerers` is this a proven fact? I’m not so sure. I get your point, but this scenario doesn’t sound like a non-exceptional case to me. Let the mods handle this when it comes up.

Comment: "Everything that we post here has a license that enables SE to hold it in perpetuity, even against our will." - You granted them that license when you posted the content. Against your will or not, you gave them the right to publish it. If you don't want to be associated with the content, you also have *that* right. Exercise it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I intentionally didn't define the "too deeply" exactly, as a precaution of getting downs because I proposed -3 while others think -2 would be enough. Although I am ready to insert an example into the suggestion.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, mods won't delete a question if it would remove reputation and work of the answerers. Furthermore, they won't intervent in non-exceptional cases, saying it is not their task (and they have right). I think you could get your proof if you would have some sticked questions.

Comment: You thought you'd get a better reaction if you were vaguer? Have you considered getting data to try to support: 1. Whether it's actually a problem; or 2. Where a sensible cut off might be? This seems a little underdone as presented. You proposed this; it's **your job** to provide the evidence.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, there were multiple posts about the ask-del misuse problem here recently; I would suggest to search for them until I get some reference.

Comment: @peterh again: your suggestion, the onus is on you. If there's a suggested reading list, include it in the question. If you're still gathering supporting material, don't post. Thus far I'm convinced neither that this is a significant problem, nor that your suggestion would improve things.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unfortunately, despite your view, the ask-del misuse problem is an existing problem, and currently I am on the way to get same examples about this. *"If you're still gathering supporting material, don't post."* <- your this sentence I can't understand, it was clear to me that my proposal will be deeply downvoted, mainly on unsaid reasons, my goal was only to show, that the solution to the problem, in my view, still exists.

Comment: So you say, but is it? I don't see what's unclear about *"my that sentence"*, but to put it another way: nobody made you post the question, so far as I'm aware. You could have spent a little more time on finding examples or running SEDE queries to support your argument *before* actually posting it, and either proved to yourself it wasn't worth discussing or demonstrated to everyone else that it was.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, it would solve the ask-del misuse problem and also the problem of the sticked questions, while it would be a peaceful and friendly way also for the new accounts and for the - mainly high-rep - answerers. Furthermore, it would enable the mods to avoid the conflict situations.

Comment: Once again, you assert without evidence. I don't mind you wasting your own time, but I'm done wasting mine.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I extended my post with the examples you wanted (although I don't think it would have any significant change to its vote count).

Comment: ...are you joking? They're meta posts, not examples of posts this change would alter, and **they're complaining about deletions**. You're proposing something that would allow **more deletions**. I'm out, have fun.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, they are meta posts, **mainly from high-rep users,** complaining about the ask-del problem. I really can't understand what is still incomprehensible for you. Maybe you need more examples? I am ready to collect them.

Comment: But this suggestion wouldn’t be addressing the ask/delete problem; it would just (conditionally) remove one of the things we have in place to *fight* that problem. No? I don’t think what you are suggesting is necessarily a bad idea, but the way it is presented seems confusing.

Comment: @Pekka웃 No, if the OPs *can* remove their sticked questions, they won't have any reason more to the ask-del misuse. Furthermore, their *already deleted* content could be undeleted without overusing the mods for non-exceptional problems.

Comment: I don’t follow the reasoning here. In my experience, ask/delete misuse typically happens when people ask things they don’t want the world to see (like interview or exam questions), when they’re just being plain selfish, when they want to keep their profile „clean“ of questions, or when they don’t realize that questions are supposed to stick around and it’s not ok to delete them right away. You seem to be thinking your change would prevent future ask/delete misuse behaviour. How would that come about? I really don’t understand.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree this can be a reason; probably many deleted questions was deleted on this reason, but note, deeply downvoted sticky questions can be also a reason for an ask-del misuse. Furthermore, even these questions could be easily undeleted on automatic ways, without mod intervention.

Comment: @peterh I still don’t follow. If you ask loads of questions that are likely to get downvoted, and delete them the moment you have a good answer, you probably need to be banned from Stack Overflow (and probably will through the automatic ban). I don’t see why their ability to delete a deeply downvoted question would change that behaviour... either way, as said it seems fair to allow users to do that.

Comment: @Pekka웃 ...and, in this case, the OP will ask his new questions on newly registered accounts, thus eliminating the problem of the question ban, while they still don't have to ask useful questions. And, the deleted questions won't be undeleted, because only mods can undelete posts deleted by their OPs. If they can delete their downvoted questions, it eliminates their reason of the harmful behavior.

Comment: @peterh it seems difficult to imagine that that’s something that happens regularly. I totally agree that a massively downvoted first question can be a huge turn-off from staying on the site and building a reputation, but I don’t think this approach would help much. And then there’s the problem how to do this on a practical level. If I want to delete my highly downvoted question, what should the system tell me? „You have to wait for the question to be downvoted even more before you can delete it“? That might even encourage some really bad behaviours....

Comment: ... like making your question intentionally *worse* so it collects more downvotes, and you can delete it.

Comment: See: [Statistics on answered questions deleted by their author](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313854/4639281). It doesn't happen very often, users who do it rarely do it more than once, and those that do end up question banned quickly. This is not a problem in need of solving at this point. As others have said, if a question has a good answer, a single upvote will prevent the question from being deleted by its owner.

Comment: @Pekka웃 No, you should be simply allowed to delete it, as you can with your unaccepted answers, or questions without upvoted answers. If the question isn't downvoted, and has upvoted answers, a message could appear, like this: *"Well, you question is not so bad, but deleting it would delete also the answer! So, please let it to remain"*. I am really surprised, what the "community" couldn't understand in this...

Comment: @TinyGiant I suspect maybe you didn't read the the *"reason"* and the *"why the current solution isn't effective"* sections enough well. Although it doesn't happen very often, it can quite annoying in both directions (1) having a sticked question getting newer and newer downvotes, or 2) if you write a good answer and the OP simply deletes it together with his question). It happens enough often, and it is enough annoying to be a regularly upcoming problem here on the meta.

Comment: (1) I understand. I still have no idea how this suggestion is going to do anything about (2).

Comment: @Pekka웃 Because the fear from the sticked question is a major motive behind the ask-del misuse. Also I did it in a time, although not here, but on the meta SE: if the first vote to my question was negative, I deleted it on the spot - only as a precaution of the sticked questions. I am nearly sure, most of the OPs have the same fear, but on the main SO site. Furthermore, I think it would an "useful" algorithm for them to ask *anything* on different, switched accounts, only to avoid the question bans (and the sticky question problem). [side note: tyvm for the human tone]

Comment: Incidents on meta are like plane crashes, there is no news report every time a plane successfully lands, similarly no one complains when the system works as expected.

Comment: @TinyGiant "There is no possibility that any perceptible change will happen within our own lifetime. We are the dead. Our only true life is in the future. We shall take part in it as handfuls of dust and splinters of bone. But how far away that future may be, there is no knowing." (George Orwell)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don’t disagree that there’s cases where it would be fair to allow the OP to delete their question, or disassociate it from their account.

Both should really be a case for moderator intervention, though, rather than an automated feature. Misuse of it would be too hard to detect.

Comment: Thank you very much for the understanding of the problem of the sticked questions (up). I think the problem of the mod interventions is in this case, that it is questionable if a sticked question would be exceptional; furthermore the mod would have to delete also the answers, including the reps collected with them, what is most probably against their intentions and customs. What would you think from a mod deleting your (possibly upvoted) post on the request of a low-rep account? No, they don't have any reason to cooperate with a new account in this case, and they have imho right.

Comment: If I accept your answer, you won't be able to delete it and maybe it will seem in the future that you were "feeding trolls". Should I accept it or not?

Comment: @peterh feel free to accept; I don’t think you’re a troll. If I ever felt like I don’t want to be associated with this Q&A (which is unlikely) I’d ask for the question to be disassociated from my account. I agree being a SO newbie, and being stuck with a highly downvoted question can be a very unpleasant and discouraging experience, but this isn’t the way to fix that.